# MacOS Catalina ldap browser supporting certificate authentication?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, certificate, ldap

I’m looking for an GUI based ldap browser here that supports certificate authentication

I previously used softerra on windows.
I’ve looked into: PhpLdap admin, Jxplorer, Ldapadmin tool.

- I checked into LdapSofts ldap browser but their product doesn’t support cert auth
- I am aware of the Directory Utility on the Mac but I don’t need a full directory and also don’t know if it can be configured as just a client with cert auth
- I have Apache Directory Studio but It doesn’t support cert auth

I’m specifically using certs from a smart card.
I need the GUI to look at specific attributes of user accounts without having to convert them; which is why I’d prefer not to use CLI.

Does anyone have a GUI tool they know works with certs?